# How to set five values to five keys in the dictionary via for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to set five values to five  keys one by one in dict

I created this code and it works but i don't think it is the best way to do that

```
import mymod
import json

final_data = list()
headers = mymod.get_headers() # This will return a list of five headers
for i in range(10):
    data = dict.fromkeys(headers,0)
    values = mymod.get_values() # This will return a list of five values
    for header in headers:
        data[header] = values[0]
        values.remove(values[0])

    final_data.append(data)

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(final_data, f, indent=4)
```

Is there a better way to do that.?

Comment: I think your question is more suited: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why do you have the `for` loop for `i`? You can remove that since you're not even accessing `i` anywhere in the loop.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more suited on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There a bug/typo in your code: `data[headers] = values[0]` is wrong.

Comment: @SamarthBhatia i don't need it i just want that code to be executed 10 times

Comment: @martineau thanks bro  i edited it is must be ```header```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

```py
import mymod
import json

final_data = list()
headers = mymod.get_headers() # This will return a list of five headers
for i in range(10):
    data = {}
    values = mymod.get_values() # This will return a list of five values
    for key, value in zip(headers, values):
        data[key] = value
    final_data.append(data)

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(final_data, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: Thank You bro this what i am looking for i really forget about ``zip``